# How to think about the lack of laws

Tags: haskell, math, types

I am a mathematician who works a lot with category theory, and I've been using Haskell for a while to perform certain computations etc., but I am definitely not a programmer. I really love Haskell and want to become much more fluent in it, and the type system is something that I find especially great to have in place when writing programs.

However, I've recently been trying to implement category theoretic things, and am running into problems concerning the fact that you seemingly can't have class method laws in Haskell. In case my terminology here is wrong, what I mean is that I can write

```
class Monoid c where
    id :: c -> c
    m :: c -> c -> c
```

but I *can't* write some law along the lines of

```
m (m x y) z ==  m x $ m y z
```

From what I gather, this is due to the lack of dependent types in Haskell, but I'm not sure how exactly this is the case (having now read a bit about dependent types). It also seems that the convention is just to include laws like this in comments and hope that you don't accidentally cook up some instance that doesn't satisfy them.

1. How should I change my approach to Haskell to deal with this problem? Is there a nice mathematical/type-theoretic solution (for example, require the existence of an associator that is an isomorphism (though then the question is, how do we encode isomorphisms without a law?)); is there some 'hack' (using extensions such as `DataKinds`); should I be drastic and switch to using something like Idris instead; or is the best response to just change the way I think about using Haskell (i.e. accept that these laws can't be implemented in a Haskelly way)?
2. (bonus) How exactly does the lack of laws come from not supporting dependent types?

Comment: Dependent types aren't necessary to express simpler laws like the one you are suggesting.  A proof-checker is.  Nearly all languages that  implement arbitrary proofs are dependently-typed, just because when you're going that far you might as well expand the universe of proofs allowed by also allowing dependent types.

Comment: Regarding 1., another thing one might ask is how one should approach python/java to deal with the lack or deficiencies of their type systems.

Comment: One approach in to translate the code into a language like Coq https://github.com/antalsz/hs-to-coq and verify it there. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-verified Another approach is to renounce a formal proof and use generative testing to try to find counterexamples to the properties http://austinrochford.com/posts/2014-05-27-quickcheck-laws.html

Comment: To expand on @danidiaz comment: the `hs-to-coq` project actually defines what it means for a `Monoid` to be lawful, and later proves that for the `Set` instances: https://github.com/antalsz/hs-to-coq/blob/d875d8ffe59b62e453dc8dd8b45af1842d03bdc5/base-thy/GHC/Base.v#L309

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to require that:

```
m (m x y) z = m x (m y z)        -- (1)
```

But to require this you need a way to check it. So you, or your compiler (or proof assistant), need to construct a proof of this. And the question is, what type is a proof of (1)?

One could imagine some `Proof` type but then maybe you could just construct a proof that `0 = 0` instead of a proof of (1) and both would have type `Proof`. So you’d need a more general type. I can’t decide how to break up the rest of the question so I’ll go for a super brief explanation of the Curry-Howard isomorphism followed by an explanation of how to prove two things are equal and then how dependent types are relevant.

---

The Curry-Howard isomorphism says that propositions are isomorphic to types and proofs are isomorphic to programs: a type corresponds to a proposition and a proof of that proposition corresponds to a program constructing a value inhabiting that type. Ignoring how many propositions might be expressed as types, an example would be that the type `A  * B` (written `(A, B)` in Haskell) corresponds to the proposition “`A` and `B`,” while the type `A + B` (written `Either A B` in Haskell) corresponds to the proposition “`A` or `B`.” Finally the type `A -> B` corresponds to “`A` implies `B`,” as a proof of this is a program which takes evidence of `A` and gives you evidence of `B`. One should note that there isn’t a way to express `not A` but one could imagine adding a type `Not A` with builtins of type `Either a (Not a)`  for the law of the excluded middle as well as `Not (Not a) -> a`, and `a * Not a -> Void` (where `Void` is a type which cannot be inhabited and therefore corresponds to false), but then one can’t really run these programs to get constructivist proofs.

Now we will ignore some realities of Haskell and imagine that there aren’t ways round these rules (in particular `undefined :: a` says everything is true, and `unsafeCoerce :: a -> b` says that anything implies anything else, or just other functions that don’t return where their existence does not imply the corresponding proof).

So we know how to combine propositions but what might a proposition be? Well one could be to say that two types are equal. In Haskell this corresponds to the GADT

```
data Eq a b where Refl :: Eq c c
```

Where this constructor corresponds to the reflexive property of equality.

[side note: if you’re still interested so far, you may be interested to look up Voevodsky’s univalent foundations, depending on how much the idea of “Homotopy type theory” interests you]

So can we prove something now? How about the transitive property of equality:

```
trans :: Eq a b -> Eq b c -> Eq a c
trans x y =
  case x of
  Refl -> -- by this match being successful, the compiler now knows that a = b
    case y of
    Refl -> -- and now b = c and so the compiler knows a = c
      Refl -- the compiler knows that this is of type Eq d d, and as it knows a = c, this typechecks as Eq a c
```

This feels like one hasn’t really proven anything (especially as this mainly relies on the compiler knowing the transitive and symmetric properties), but one gets a similar feeling when proving simple things in logic as well.

---

So now how might you prove the original proposition (1)? Well let’s imagine we want a type `c` to be a monoid then we should also prove that $\forall x,y,z:c, m (m x y) z = m x (m y z).$ So we need a way to express `m (m x y) z` as a type. Strictly speaking this isn’t dependent types (this can be done with `DataKinds` to promote values and type families instead of functions). But you do need dependent types to have types depend on values. Specifically if you have a type `Nat` of natural numbers and a type family `Vec :: Nat -> *` (`*` is the kind (read type) of all types) of fixed length vectors, you could define a dependently typed function `mkVec :: (n::Nat) -> Vec n`. Observe how the type of the output depends on the *value* of the input.

So your law needs to have functions promoted to type level (skipping the questions about how one defines type equality and value equality), as well as dependent types (made up syntax):

```
class Monoid c where
  e :: c
  (*) :: c -> c -> c
  idl :: (x::c) -> Eq x (e * x)
  idr :: (x::c) -> Eq x (x * e)
  assoc :: (x::c) -> (y::c) -> (z::c) -> Eq ((x * y) * z) (x * (y * z))
```

Observe how types tend to become large with dependent types and proofs. In a language missing typeclasses one could put such values into a record.

---

Final note on the theory of dependent types and how these correspond to the curry Howard isomorphism.

Dependent types can be considered an answer to the question: what types correspond to the propositions $\forall x\in S\quad P(x)$ and $\exists y\in T\quad Q(y)?$

The answer is that you create new ways to make types: the dependent product and the dependent sum (coproduct). The dependent product expresses “for all values $x$ of type $S,$ there is a value of type $P(x).$” A normal product would be a dependent product with $S=2,$ a type inhabited by two values. A dependent product might be written `(x:T) -> P x`. A dependent sum says “some value $y$ of type $T$, paired with a value of type $Q(y).$” this might be written `(y:T) * Q y`.

One can think of these as a generalisation of arbitrarily indexed (co)products from Set to general categories, where one might sensibly write e.g. $\prod_\Lambda X(\lambda),$ and sometimes such notation is used in type theory.

Comment: This answer is great, thank you ! So is this example code that you give for Monoid something that you can actually compile in Haskell using `DataKinds`, or is it subtler than that ? I'm really interested in HoTT but it's very much not my field of study, so am still getting to grips with a lot of the basics.

Comment: The code I give is made up in the style of Haskell. I think if you want to prove things then I think you need something like idris or agda or coq. I vaguely recall there was some way to ask ghc to try to prove that two things are equal. It isn’t perfect (it will apply the inliner and optimiser to both sides so only works for simple things)  but maybe someone will mention it.

Comment: The type of `Refl` should be just `Eq a a`, not `a -> a -> Eq a a`, no? Also worth noting that the `a` in `data Eq a b` is distinct from that in `Eq a a`; you could just as well write `Refl :: Eq x x`. When I first encountered this I thought “Doesn’t that mean `Eq a b` is a proof that `a ~ a`, ignoring `b`?” when in fact it is a proof of `a ~ b` as claimed.

Comment: @JonPurdy yes you’re right. I’ve edited to correct that